# Jenkins job cannot find terraform installation and fails with error

Tags: jenkins, terraform

I am setting up a Jenkins pipeline which will deploy a spring boot application to EKS. I have the same application installed using cloudformation and works fine. I am now trying to migrate it over to use terraform. I have terraform installed on the ec2 Ubuntu box in the /usr/bin directory and have the terraform plugin installed and configured as shown in the picture. [image]

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        terraform 'terraform-11'
    }
    
    triggers {
        pollSCM '* * * * *'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Terraform init') {
            steps {
                sh 'terraform init'
            }
        }
        stage('Terraform apply') {
            steps {
                sh 'terraform apply --auto-approve'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my pipeline code which errors out with the following error:

- terraform init
  /var/jenkins_home/jobs/hello-job-aws-terrform/workspace@tmp/durable-48ffb117/script.sh: 1:
  /var/jenkins_home/jobs/hello-job-aws-terrform/workspace@tmp/durable-48ffb117/script.sh: terraform: not found

Comment: The Terraform plugin is long unsupported. Try using an agent with Terraform installed (such as the official Docker image for Terraform) and the Jenkins Pipeline library for Terraform instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        TERRAFORM_HOME = tool name: 'terraform-11', type: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation'
        PATH = "${TERRAFORM_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    }
    
    triggers {
        pollSCM '* * * * *'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Terraform init') {
            steps {
                sh 'terraform init'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Terraform apply') {
            steps {
                sh 'terraform apply --auto-approve'
            }
        }
    }
}
```